# all_trips Webhooks: Find out which user the status_changed is for

Tags: uber-api

I've got the Webhooks working for our developer accounts, and it emits a status_changed message every time there is an Uber request, even if the request was not initiated from our app (using the "all_trips" permission)

When we get the response back, how do we determine which user this is for? E.g. in the response below, there is no way to determine that and using the server token to authenticate to the resource_href gives an "Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided" error.

> {
>      "event_id": "3a3f3da4-14ac-4056-bbf2-d0b9cdcb0777",
>      "event_time": 1427343990,
>      "event_type": "all_trips.status_changed",
>      "meta": {
>          "resource_id": "2a2f3da4",
>          "resource_type": "request",
>          "status": "accepted"
>      },
>      "resource_href": "https://api.uber.com/v1/requests/2a2f3da4"
>   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! We rolled out a fix that adds the users UUID as an additional field in the "meta" section, as well as updated our documentation here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks

Let us know if you have any more trouble!

Comment: Thank you! One issue I notice is that the webhook calls are fairly inconsistent -- the server often doesn't notify us. (We don't even see the calls on our end). Any idea what could be causing these?

Comment: Hey Rohan,

Yes there are some known inconsistency issues with our webhook notifications that our engineering team is currently working through. You're not missing all webhook correct, you're just receiving them inconsistently?

Comment: yes, we occasionally miss the webhook notifications. makes testing a bit hard since it's unclear what went wrong.